# Create multiple pivot tables based on variable sheet numbers using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with a number of sheets, all of which contain tables as below:

| Supplier | Category | Contract ID | Document Name | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Company A | Clothing | ABC27123 | Contract_Name_1 | 80% |
| Company A | Clothing | ABC27123 | Contract_Name_2 | 35% |
| Company B | Telecoms | DB21HG3A | Contract_7 | 77% |
| Company C | Autos | 9HRT76X1 | Contract_signed_1 | 56% |
| Company C | Autos | 9HRT76X1 | Contract_Amendment | 90% |
| Company C | Autos | 9HRT76X1 | Contract_reviewed_2 | 45% |

All sheets that contain these tables are titled `Lever 1`, `Lever 2`, `Lever 3` and so on. The tables are also named after the sheets(i.e. `Lever_1`, `Lever_2`, `Lever_3` etc). The number of sheets varies from one use case to another, but the data inside of them will always be in the same format as above.

I am trying to create a script that will create a new sheet titled `Pivots` where a pivot table will be created for each of the `Lever` sheets. The Pivot Tables should use the columns `Contract ID` & `Document Name` as rows and the `Max of Score` as values. I have attached an example below.

[image]

Can anyone help point me in the right direction? I'm new to VBA and I'm not sure where exactly to start.

Comment: Start by creating a pivot while recording a macro, then use the recorded code as a starting point.

Comment: Play around with the Macro Recorder for a bit, just as Tim suggested.  You'll learn a ton, and you'll almost certainly answer your own question quicker than anyone else here, given the scenario that you described above.

Answer (score 0):

Try, The premise is that the data of each sheet is from cell a1.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, pWs As Worksheet
    Dim vName() As Variant
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim pc As PivotCache
    Dim pv As PivotTable
    Dim Fd As PivotField
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim Target As Range
    
    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each Ws In Worksheets
        If InStr(Ws.Name, "Pivot") Then
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vName(1 To n)
            vName(n) = Ws.Name
        End If
    Next Ws
    
    If n Then
        Worksheets(vName).Delete
    End If
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    n = 0
    For Each Ws In Worksheets
        If InStr(Ws.Name, "Lever") Then
            n = n + 1
           
            Set rngDB = Ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
            Set pWs = Worksheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))

            With pWs
                .Name = "Pivot " & n
                Set Target = .Range("a1")
            End With
            
            Set pc = Wb.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=rngDB)
            Set pv = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=Target, TableName:="Pivot " & n)
            With pv
                Set Fd = .PivotFields("Contract ID")
                With Fd
                    .Orientation = xlRowField
                    .Position = 1
                End With
                Set Fd = .PivotFields("Document Name")
                With Fd
                    .Orientation = xlRowField
                    .Position = 2
                End With
                Set Fd = .PivotFields("Score")
                With Fd
                    .Orientation = xlDataField
                    .Function = xlMax
                    .Position = 1
                End With
            End With
        End If
    Next Ws
                
End Sub
```